# Code Model Import for Class with Embedded Enum

Tags: java, jcodemodel

I'm working on generating some Java classes using CodeModel and I'm having some trouble adding import statements for classes that have embedded static Enum

For example if I have a class and create an instance variable...

```
Class<?> clazz = getPackageClass();
cls.field(JMod.PRIVATE, codeModel._ref(sourceClass), "testUnderlying");
```

But this creates code like...

```
import com.test.platform.xxx.UnderlyingType;
....
private UnderlyingType testUnderlying;
```

However, if UnderlyingType had a enum field that I want to invoke a static method on (e.g. valueOf)...

```
private UnderlyingType.EnumType enum;
...
...
UnderlyingType.EnumType.valueOf(xxx);
```

it seems to confuse CodeModel and instead of having a seprate import and the instance variable I will get

```
private com.test.platform.xxx.UnderlyingType testUnderlying;
```

Is it possible invoke the static method without losing the import?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a comment in the JCodeModel code that mentions why they don't import inner classes:

```
    /**
     * Returns true if the symbol represented by the short name
     * is "importable".
     */
    public boolean collisions(JDefinedClass enclosingClass) {
        // special case where a generated type collides with a type in package java
        ...
        if(c.outer()!=null)
            return true; // avoid importing inner class to work around 6431987. Also see jaxb issue 166
        }
    ...
    }
```

Not sure what 6431987 is referring to (possibly an internal SUN bug tracker) but here is the referenced jaxb issue:

https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/JAXB-166/JAXB-166.html

Seems they were having trouble with imports from inner classes colliding.

Worth noting, this fork of JCodeModel fixes this issue: https://github.com/UnquietCode/JCodeModel